# Error While Comparing Data Table Value With Another Value

Tags: c#, oracle

Here values from usergroup is filling into dt. Now I want to check if value of code inside the data table dt is equal to "ABC". Error is showing for if (dt._CODE = "ABC").

The values are filling into data table Dt.

```
DbDataAdapter da = _dataFactory.CreateDataAdapter();
DbParameter param1 = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable("USER1");
try{
    conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
    conn.Open();
    string _sql1 = "SELECT * FROM USERGROUP WHERE CODE='ABC' ";
    da.SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = OracleHelper.FixCommandText(_sql1);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleHelper.CreateParameter(ref da, ref param108, "@CODE", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input,_code);
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt._CODE = "ABC")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be like :

```
if (dt._CODE == "ABC")
```

?

You using assignment rather than equality check (==)